# Error while comparing image from database

Tags: java, sql, compare, blob, photo

I want to compare imported images with images from database. So far I have created this but I keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at sun.awt.image.FileImageSource.getDecoder(FileImageSource.java:35)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:240)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

Here is my code:

```
String file1 = "C:\\Users\\Seth\\Desktop\\Capstone\\bill.jpg";
String file2;

public void DBImages() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL";
    Connection conn = null;
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "c##lambros", "16111111");
    String sql = "SELECT foto FROM criminals WHERE criminal_id = 1";
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
    byte[] bytes = null;
    while (rset.next()) {

        bytes = rset.getBytes(1);
        file2 = bytes.toString();
        processImage();
    }
}


public void processImage() {


    Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
    Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file2);

    try {

        PixelGrabber grab1 = new PixelGrabber(image1, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
        PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(image2, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);

        int[] data1 = null;

        if (grab1.grabPixels()) {
            int width = grab1.getWidth();
            int height = grab1.getHeight();
            data1 = new int[width * height];
            data1 = (int[])grab1.getPixels();
        }

        int[] data2 = null;

        if (grab2.grabPixels()) {
            int width = grab2.getWidth();
            int height = grab2.getHeight();
            data2 = new int[width * height];
            data2 = (int[])grab2.getPixels();
        }

        System.out.println("Pixels equal: " + java.util.Arrays.equals(data1, data2));

    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    CompareImage compare = new CompareImage();
    compare.processImage();
}
```

I think my logic is correct. Why can't the method fetch the image from the database?

Comment: @Kayaman How do i convert a byte[] sequence to image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your line

```
file2 = bytes.toString();
```

is completely wrong. In no way would it ever write the bytes to a file. You clearly haven't done any File IO in Java.

You can bypass the file writing anyways, if you have enough memory. You can wrap the `byte[]` in a `ByteArrayInputStream` and use `ImageIO.read()` to get the Image out of that.

```
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
Image img = ImageIO.read(in);
```

Comment: OK! and the img? How do I make it a file?

Comment: Do you need it to be a file? Seems like an unnecessary step in your comparison. Anyways, go read the File IO tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: Not exactly but how do I use it in here gor file2?

Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file2);

Comment: Pass it as a parameter. You already have the Image object, you don't need to load it again.

Comment: hhmmm.. ok! I did this: 

        `Image image1 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(file1);
        Image image2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(img.toString());`

and I am still getting a nullpointerexception. Not the same one though!

Comment: Can you suggest what should I put there?

Comment: You already have the Image, you don't need to use the Toolkit for that anymore. And stop using toString() everywhere, it's like you're putting things randomly without thinking at all.

Comment: OK so i did this with the img but I am still getting an exception

`PixelGrabber grab1 = new PixelGrabber(image1, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);
            PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, -1, -1, false);`

Comment: Well what's the exception.

Comment: well that would be nice since I have no idea what to do.. but no! just the part where it will give me NO exception...

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.image.PixelGrabber.<init>(PixelGrabber.java:168)
 at CompareImage.processImage(CompareImage.java:66)
 at CompareImage.main(CompareImage.java:95)
`

Comment: On line 66 you have a null reference. That causes errors, so find out what's null and then fix it so that it won't be null in the method. Edit the post and put your current code there.

Comment: it's the
`PixelGrabber grab2 = new PixelGrabber(img, 0, 0, -1, -1, false); `

That's why I am asking. I fetched the image from the DB inside img but why is it null?`